# How to get the available/free memory from ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I tried `adb shell top`, but it gives too much details info.

What I need is just the total available memory. How to get it via ADB?

Comment: [here is good](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-porting/MHPg0P6OS30) discussion regarding how to interpret those values - and which are other options to get "free" memory amount

Answer (score 40):

Why not built-in::

```
$ adb shell "cat /proc/meminfo"
```

Most phones lack `free` utility and all the more buzybox. On other hand `/proc/meminfo` is integral part of Linux.

Comment: after getting this output the `free` memory can be calculated by adding `MemFree` and `SwapFree`

Comment: `watch -n 0.5 adb shell "cat /proc/meminfo" ` this can make this comment more useful

Answer (score 24):

The most "clean" way I found so far is `adb shell vmstat`

It gives the info as below:

```
procs  memory                       system          cpu
 r  b    free mapped   anon   slab    in   cs  flt  us ni sy id wa ir
 1  0   99120  55400 618680  25600  2207 4089    0   6  0  9 84  0  0
```

in which, the `99120` is the free memory in KB.

Comment: Not quite, there's a difference between free and available memory due to caches and buffers that can be erased when needed. vmstat shows 'free' as opposed to total available. `/proc/meminfo`'s `MemAvailable` column is a much better descriptor. My android dev board has 1GB of RAM, `vmstat` shows about 256MB free. `/proc/meminfo` shows the same 256MB free, but shows that about 650MB are actually _available_ for programs to use.

Answer (score 17):

You could also take a look at [dumpsys](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys)

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo
```

example output

```
Applications Memory Usage (in Kilobytes):
Uptime: 466195106 Realtime: 1351644497

Total PSS by process:
    358,901K: org.mozilla.firefox (pid 28883 / activities)
...
...
...

Total PSS by OOM adjustment:
    420,346K: Native
        125,116K: surfaceflinger (pid 734)
         43,238K: logd (pid 488)
         20,419K: mm-qcamera-daemon (pid 3307)
...
...
...
Total PSS by category:
    649,878K: Native
    407,027K: Dalvik
    241,132K: Gfx dev
    178,217K: Unknown
    174,912K: GL mtrack
    161,148K: EGL mtrack
    129,137K: .art mmap
     96,374K: Dalvik Other
     91,936K: .apk mmap
     67,291K: .dex mmap
     63,269K: .so mmap
     34,888K: Stack
     25,226K: .oat mmap
      5,967K: Other mmap
      1,617K: Other dev
      1,439K: Ashmem
        894K: .jar mmap
         68K: .ttf mmap
          8K: Cursor
          0K: Other mtrack

Total RAM: 3,868,864K (status normal)
 Free RAM: 1,114,394K (  907,794K cached pss +    38,964K cached kernel +   167,636K free)
 Used RAM: 3,259,174K (2,762,994K used pss +   496,180K kernel)
 Lost RAM:   358,896K
     ZRAM:   285,780K physical used for 1,434,012K in swap (1,442,368K total swap)
   Tuning: 256 (large 512), oom   558,304K, restore limit   186,101K (high-end-gfx)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using `busybox`?

```
adb shell busybox free -m
             total         used         free       shared      buffers
Mem:           741          503          237            0            5
-/+ buffers:                498          242
Swap:            0            0            0
```